# How can convert numbers to words on load event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I did a javascript is working fine and translating numbers to words.

But is doing the action only when I do click on "CALCULATE" and want to show the translation without typing or doing click just assing the value

Here is the view

```
<form>
 Number to words<BR>
 <BR>Number/N&uacute;mero 
 <INPUT NAME="Number" TYPE="text" SIZE="60" value="123"><BR>
 <INPUT NAME="Calc" TYPE="button" VALUE="Calculate" ONCLICK="Calculate(this.form)">
 <INPUT NAME="Reset" TYPE="button" VALUE="Reset" ONCLICK="ClearForm(this.form)">
 <BR>
 Spanish<BR><TEXTAREA NAME="Spanish" ROWS="5" COLS="90"></TEXTAREA><BR>
</form>
```

Here is the demo     http://jsfiddle.net/RQ7R4/13/

Somebody can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The following will both 'translate' on load AND while you type** -- but be careful, it can keep your browser too busy *if you have a high number of form elements that have to be read*:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name=Number]').on('keyup change blur',function() {
        Calculate( this.form );
    });
    Calculate( $('form')[0] );
});
```

[**AMAZINGLY WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RQ7R4/14/)

I had to change the `input` element `type` from `text` to `number` so it can only respond to number -- some auto-validation of sorts:

```
<INPUT NAME="Number" TYPE="number" SIZE="60" value="123"><BR>
```

Comment: How can i do to make this fast?

Comment: For a small form like the one you have, there's nothing to worry about. If you had a form with a lot more input elements that it would have to read to perform the 'translations' then you could concerned. In such a case you would use just `blur` and `change` events.

Comment: Ok seems to be working there but can you help me converting to prototype? http://jsfiddle.net/RQ7R4/21/ because I see uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function .......prototype.

Comment: I don't 'speak' prototype but if you add the appropriate events to this one: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/RQ7R4/22/ to replace `click` you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

```
<INPUT NAME="Number" TYPE="text" SIZE="60" value="123" onchange="Calculate(this.form)">
```

If you tab out of the field it will call the Calculate function. I would suggest you explore jQuery or AngularJS if you require something advanced.

Comment: Or knockout.js, which is like angular, but more lightweight

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RQ7R4/17/ Edited your fiddle. Just type sum numbers in the field and click outside it